# iOS EventKit EKCalendar unique (global) identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, eventkit, ekevent

Is there a property that can be used to recognize calendars across devices?

According to the Apple docs, the "calendarIdentifier" property cannot be used:

> A full sync with the calendar will lose this identifier. You should have a plan for dealing with a calendar whose identifier is no longer fetch-able by caching its other properties.

I'm looking for something similar to EKEvent.calendarItemExternalIdentifier, which is the same and unique across devices, but for Calendars.

Comment: Have you had any progress with this? I've seen an answer somewhere suggesting going for matching the title and the color of the calendar, but this would still not work in many situations (e.g. if the user changes the title/color of a calendar, or if there are multiple sources setup with similar calendars).